# passing the property of an object to another object as a key

Tags: javascript

Lets say I have an object with image urls.

```
const imageURL = {
  brakePad: "some_url_string",
  tieRodEnd: "some_url_string",
  rackEnd: "some_url_string",
};
```

I also have an array of products.

```
const products = [
      {
        type : 'brakePad',
        brand : 'Akebono',
        img : // i would like to pass the type value to the 
              // imageURL object to get the url ; in this instance 
              // brakePad
              // i know i can pass it as img: imageURL['brakePad']
              // but that is not what i am trying to achieve.
              // is there any way i could extract the value of 
              // the type property and pass it to the imageURL 
              //object as the key 
      } ,
      {
        // similar object
      },
      
];
```

i would like to pass the type value to the
imageURL object to get the url.
i know i can pass it as img: imageURL['brakePad']
but that is not what i am trying to achieve.
is there any way i could extract the value of
the type property and pass it to the imageURL
object as the key
Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? StackOverflow is not a free coding service. You are expected to invest your best effort to solve the problem by yourself first. Then, if you fail, search the web for why it might fail. If you've done all that and still didn't succeed, come back here, show your best attempt, explain how it fails and what you expect instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get an array of `URL's` from iterating over the `products` array.

```
const result = imageURL[products[0].type];
```

```js
const products = [
  {
    type: "brakePad",
    brand: "Akebono",
    img: "url",
  },
  {
    type: "tieRodEnd",
    brand: "Akebono",
    img: "url",
  },
];

const imageURL = {
  brakePad: "some_url_string",
  tieRodEnd: "some_url_string",
  rackEnd: "some_url_string",
};

const result = products.map((o) => imageURL[o.type]);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the products array and then use the type value for each product,
e.g using `for...of` loop,

```js
for (let product of products) {
  // here you have access to individual product
  imageURL[product.type] // brakepad, tierodend ...
}
```

or conventional `for loop`:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
  const type = products[i].type
  imageURL[type]
}
```

If you want to add the image URL to the product objects you can map over the products array e.g,

```js
const imageURL = {
  brakePad: "some_url_string",
  tieRodEnd: "some_url_string",
  rackEnd: "some_url_string",
}

const products = [
  {
    type: 'brakePad',
    brand: 'Akebono',
  },
  {
  type: 'tieRodEnd',
  brand: 'MONSTER',
  }
]

const newProducts = products.map((product)=> {
  return {...product, img: imageURL[product.type]}
})

console.log(newProducts)
```

You can read more about `map` method [here at mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Or if you would like to add to the existing objects instead of creating a new array using `map`, then:

```js
for (let product of products) {
  product.img = imageURL[product.type]
}
console.log(products)
```

Comment: but i would like to store the image link in the product object itself but not hard code it. so something like img : imageUrl[this.type] .... but i am not sure about the exact syntax or if the 'this' keyword can be used for anonymous objects.